# xampp localhost не работает на windows 10

Tags: localhost, xampp

Не работает localhost на xampp. До этого не работал apache. Поменял порт с 80 на 8080 и ssl port с 443 на 1443, после этого apache запустился. Но когда пишу localhost в браузере, то там не запускается.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *поменял порт с 80 на 8080 и ssl port с 443 на 1443 после этого apache запустился.* У вас значит эти порты уже использовались на тот момент. Часто бывает что скайп их использует. А раз поменяли порт то впишите *localhost:8080* а не просто *localhost*.

Comment: @Moonvvell пашет)) спасибо, помогли

Comment: @Moonvvell, пожалуйста, перенесите ваш комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @NursultanKenzhegaliyev не забудьте принять ответ

Answer (score 1):

> Поменял порт с 80 на 8080 и ssl port с 443 на 1443 после этого apache
>   запустился.

У вас значит эти порты уже использовались на тот момент. Часто бывает что скайп их использует. Простейший выход - сначала запускаете ксамп потом скайп. А раз поменяли порт то впишите *localhost:8080* а не просто *localhost*.